# remove default nginx welcome page when access directly from ip address

Tags: ubuntu, nginx

At my ubuntu server, I install nginx and setup virtual host using this article.
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-set-up-nginx-virtual-hosts-server-blocks-on-ubuntu-12-04-lts--3

The virtual host's domain name is like www.example.com. When I go to www.example.com, I can see my application's index page. However, when I go to the real ip address, I still see the nginx welcome page. What can I do to remove this welcome page or point to www.example.com if someone uses ip address to access my site?

I setup a A record to point ip xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx to www.example.com.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

I think when you first set up nginx it comes with a `default` virtual host. Did you try removing that? Did you try deleting the symlink?
A third option would be to add a `deny all;` on the location `/` of the default virtual host.

I am not exactly sure if that will work and I cannot test it right now. If the above does not work, try this out: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/request_processing.html#how_to_prevent_undefined_server_names

`http://your-server-ip/` is a request with undefined server name. You should be able to block it with:

```
server {
    listen      80;
    server_name "";
    return      444;
}
```

Comment: I already removed default one from /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/.

Comment: the 3rd option works. I just give this undefined server to my virtual host config and then restart nginx. It works!

Answer (score 56):

You need to remove the file `default`, located in `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled`:

```
rm /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default
```

Then restart nginx:

```
service nginx reload
```

Comment: It resolved my issue. However, I've prefixed the commands with `sudo`. Cheers :)

Comment: If you disable the default site, nginx will use the first encountered matching server block as a fallback site instead.

Answer (score 23):

If you want to remove the default nginx server block you can use the command:

```
sudo unlink /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default
```

This removes the symlink from the folder: `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/`.

There will still be file `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default` but it will not be active anymore.

If you have another server block that handles your domain e.g. example.com with some website there, than if someone goes to ip address of your server, than your website for example.com will be served.

If you have multiple domains, you need multiple server blocks. To ensure that one of those blocks serves as default one you can edit `/etc/nginx/sites-available/example.com` to have `default_server` option in the listen directive, e.g.:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    root /var/www/html;
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name _;

    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
}
```

Comment: Adding the `default_server` to port 80 is what did it for me.

Answer (score 7):

Configing to

```
server {
    listen      80;
    server_name xxxx;
    return      444;
}
```

I get 502 for all uri, including my application url.

---

I didn't find `sites_enabled` folder under `/etc/nginx`, instead, my default site locates in `/usr/share/nginx/html`

So I create another blank page located in

`/usr/share/nginx/html/blank`

create a blank index.html

```
# echo >> index.html
```

then edit the default.conf

```
location / {
    root   /usr/share/nginx/html/blank;
    index  index.html ;
}
```

then the home page becomes blank, hiding nginx info.

---

By the way, if you remove

```
location / {
    root   /usr/share/nginx/html/blank;
    index  index.html ;
}
```

or set

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ = 404;
}
```

you will get 404 on homepage, but showing "Nginx version", which is not good.

Comment: If i'm going to go thru this much effort, might as well secure by removing Nginx version so +1 for blank index.html

Answer (score 6):

To `disable` a site, for instance, the `default`:

```
rm /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default
```

`/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default` is just a symlink to `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default`. So removing it will not remove the original.

To `enable` a site:

```
cd /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/
ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/<mysite>
```

Finally to reload changes:

```
sudo systemctl reload nginx.service
```

Answer (score 5):

If you removed `default` under `/etc/nginx/sites-available` and restarted nginx and the welcome page is still showing, then see if there is a `default.conf` under `/etc/nginx/conf.d` and delete it and then restart nginx.

Comment: I did both already but I am here because the page still shows.

Answer (score 3):

The default virtual host is generally located on `/etc/nginx/conf.d/` or `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/` (as symlink)

Remove the default virtual host from all the possible locations:

```
rm -rf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
rm -rf /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default.conf
rm -rf /etc/nginx/sites-available/default.conf
```

And then restart `nginx`:

```
service nginx restart
```

Check your includes on `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` if it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had to remove *two* links to the default site:

```
sudo mv /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf.bak
sudo rm /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default
```

Answer (score -1):

The above suggestions worked for me, the default server was blocking GitLab for me. If you want to keep the `default` file for later use and not deleting it, the line  below
in  `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` can be commented by placing a # in front of it:

```sh
#    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
```

You can reload nginx afterward

```sh
nginx -s reload
```

Or restart it from system control

```
sudo systemctl restart nginx
```