# Droplet Public IP points to nginx Welcome Page, but domain points to index.html

Tags: nginx, digital-ocean

I followed this tutorial (https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-nginx-on-ubuntu-20-04#step-1-installing-nginx), and was able to install nginx and ran all the steps specified.

I have no nginx syntax errors, nginx is running successfully, as I'm able to see the nginx page when I connect to my droplet's public IP.

When I go to either this public IP and my domain, I expect to see a simple index.html file I made that just says "hello world".

I'm not sure why I keep seeing the nginx page when I go to this public IP. I made sure to create a symlink to enable my domain's config file, and followed this tutorials steps exactly as specified. It's strange that I'm able to see index.html when visiting my website domain, but keep seeing just the nginx welcome page when visiting the droplet's public IP.

I suspect it has something to do with my DNS settings and/or the way my nginx config is set up, but I'm at a total loss.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: NVM. I found a related thread, answered my own question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19215641/remove-default-nginx-welcome-page-when-access-directly-from-ip-address?rq=2